# Fetch entities from a table and sum a field - Sequelize

Tags: mysql, node.js, mariadb, sequelize.js

i am trying to find all and count rows from a table and sum a field. I tried this query but it's not working as expected.

```
A.findAndCountAll({
   where: {userId: id},
   include: [[sequelize.fn('sum', sequelize.col('price')), 'totalPrice'],]
})
```

This query return **only one** entity in this object format:

```
{
   count: x, // correct
   rows[{
          A.qqq,
          ....
          totalPrice: x // also correct
       }]
}
```

So what i am looking for is a query that returns **all the entities** that i am querying and the sum outside the rows array.
Something like this:

```
{
    count: x,
    rows: [...],
    totalPrice: x
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of stressing your Database with additional computing, you could easily do both count and sum (total price) using a `.reduce` function.

Comment: Yes, that'w what i am doing. But i want some trick using DB.